# Solving a weird system of ODEs: $-(\lambda_i+\delta)v_i(x)+\mu_iv_i(x) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_i^2 v_i''(x) +\lambda_iv_{3-i}(x)=0, ~~~~~i=1,2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am reading the following [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167668711000035)
I having trouble understanding how they solve the following system.

$$-(\lambda_i+\delta)v_i(x)+\mu_iv'_i(x) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_i^2 v_i''(x) +\lambda_iv_{3-i}(x)=0, ~~~~~i=1,2\\\\\\$$

The parameters $\lambda_i,\delta,\mu_i,\sigma_i, $  are just some constants.

This equation in the[article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167668711000035) is label as equation (3) at the third paragraph just after Lemma 3.1 therein.

I n a simple writing the above equation can be readily rewritten as follow. 
$$-(\lambda_1+\delta)v_1(x)+\mu_1v'_1(x) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_1^2 v_1''(x) +\lambda_1v_{2}(x)=0. $$

$$-(\lambda_2+\delta)v_2(x)+\mu_2v'_2(x) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_2^2 v_2''(x) +\lambda_2v_{1}(x)=0. $$
The unknown are $v_1$ and $v_2$.

where we respectively replace $i$ by $1$ and $2$.

For sake of simplicity assume that all the constants are chosen so that this system posses a general solution $(v_1,v_2)$.

> How do I solve this system I tried put this equation in the matrix form (X'=AX)using substitution but couldn't end up with something very clear.

I would like to to find an elegant way to solve the system.  Any hint or solution is warmly welcome.

Note that I do not really care about the constants(They aere actually pointless) I just want any method with which I could overcome such equation.

Comment: You made a mistake on the right side with $\lambda_2v_1$

Comment: @Isham yes sure you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$-(\lambda_1+\delta)v_1(x)+\mu_1v_1(x) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_1^2 v_1''(x) +\lambda_1v_{2}(x)=0. $$

$$-(\lambda_2+\delta)v_2(x)+\mu_2v_2(x) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_2^2 v_2''(x) +\lambda_2v_{1}(x)=0. $$
Which can be written as
$$\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\vec{V}(x)+\Omega\vec{V}(x)=0$$
With $\vec{V}(x)=\begin{bmatrix}v_{1}(x) & v_{2}(x)  \end{bmatrix}^{T}$, and
$$\Omega=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{\sigma_{1}^{2}}(\mu_{1}-(\lambda_{1}+\delta)) & \frac{2}{\sigma_{1}^{2}}\lambda_{1} \\
\frac{2\lambda_{2}}{\sigma_{2}^{2}} & \frac{2}{\sigma_{2}^{2}}(\mu_{2}-(\lambda_{2}+\delta)  \end{bmatrix})$$
By letting
$$\vec{V}(x)=\vec{V}_{0}e^{i\omega{x}}$$
You arrive at the eigenvalue problem
$$\Omega\vec{V}_{0}=\omega^{2}\vec{V}_{0}$$
Which gives four solutions $\omega\in\{\pm\lambda_{1}, \pm\lambda_{2}\}$, where $\lambda_{1, 2}$ are eigenvalues of $\Omega$. If the corresponding eigenvectors are $\vec{v}_{1, 2}$, the general solution is given by
$$\vec{V}(x)=\vec{v}_{1}(c_{1}e^{i\lambda_{1}{x}}+c_{2}e^{-i\lambda_{1}{x}})+\vec{v}_{2}(c_{3}e^{i\lambda_{2}{x}}+c_{4}e^{-i\lambda_{2}{x}})$$
Where $c_{1}, ..., c_{4}$ are constants.

Comment: thanks very much for this insight but unfortunately i forgot the first order derivative. have a look to the update.

Comment: using your trtick I got an equation of the form. $AX''+BX'+CX= 0$  How do I proceed from there?

Comment: perform the same substitution $X(x)=X_{0}\exp(i\omega{x})$, to give $(-A\omega^{2}+iB\omega+C)X_{0}=0$, for nontrivial solutions require $\det(-A\omega^{2}+iB\omega+C)=0$ and the eigenvectors are simply $\ker(-A\omega^{2}+iB\omega+C)$.